# How to use Material Ui Select input prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out why material-ui `InputBase` is working while native HTML is not.

The `input` prop has defined this way in the doc
***An Input element; does not have to be a material-ui specific Input.***

Working example:

```
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select"
import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase"
import styled from "styled-components"

const Input = styled(InputBase)`
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
`
   <FormControl>
       <Select input={<Input/>} >
         <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
     </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

Not working, meaning the `MenutItem` or `option` will not show if I click the Select component

```
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select"
import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase"
import styled from "styled-components"

const Input = styled.select`
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
`
   <FormControl>
       <Select input={<Input/>} >
         <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
     </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

doc reference: https://material-ui.com/api/select/

Answer (score 0):

> An Input element; does not have to be a material-ui specific Input.

It's about the input prop which you're passing to `Select` component. `InputBase` should be there as it might be rendering the `Select` as children.

Comment: if InputBase is children of select how can select be the children of input ?